# How do I reliably check if I am inside systemd shell invoked by "systemd-run --shell"?

Tags: bash, systemd, fish

`systemd-run` provides `--shell` flag, that opens a new session. I often test high-memory applications and I use it like this:

`systemd-run --slice=restrict_memory.slice --shell --user`

Then, when I run an application and if it exceeds memory limit defined in `restrict_memory.slice`, OOM just kills this exact shell and I can continue with my work.

What I want is to reliably check if the shell I'm currently in is created through `systemd-run --shell`. Right now I check if `SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID` environment variable is greater than 2000 and display that I'm running inside systemd shell in the prompt (I use fish shell). I just noticed that this value is higher if I'm inside systemd shell, but I want a more reliable way to check this.

Tried googling this but did not find any results.

Comment: not an answer but a workaround: add `-E FOOBAR=1` to your `systemd-run` calls to set an env var in the environment that you can check for.

Comment: apart from that I don't think it is possible, because I think *all* shells on a systemd system are started that way, no? Perhaps the better question is: is it possible to detect the slice on the current shell?

Comment: I find `pstree -sap $$` useful in exploring this in case you haven't yet tried that.

Comment: You can always check your cgroup name -- see `cat /proc/self/cgroups`; you'll see the slice included.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianFritz - I went with this approach, just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if grep -Fe /restrict-memory.slice/ /proc/self/cgroups; then
  echo "Running inside a restricted slice"
else
  echo "NOT running inside a restricted slice"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution without setting env variable